# how it possible ,select the value from dependent dropdown list and insert it into database table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

inserting the value from dynamic drop down list using jQuery ajax in Laravel .how it is possible?
I search many but not get any answer so help me

Comment: Its hard to answer your question, its compareable to this one: *"I want a car, it should have one pink door, how can i do that?"*. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: for example, you have countries drop down right, so every time user selects you to want that selected values to be inserted in databse? pls elaborate a bit more so we can answer your question in a better way!

Comment: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-make-simple-dependent-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax-in-laravel-5example.html

Comment: let suppose we have 4 tables compnay ,model ,variant and ads ,company model have one to many rel ,model and variant have one to many ,so in the drop down when i select a specific company the related models should appear in next drop down .same thing apply on variant ,when i select these values from drop downs i want to submit these values in ads table ,,hope this will help